# linux + yum update - what this command covers?

Tags: security, yum, upgrade

I verified what are the missing security patches as the following:

```
yum updateinfo list security available
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
RHSA-2016:0073 security bind-libs-32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.6.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0073 security bind-utils-32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.6.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0428 security libssh2-1.4.2-2.el6_7.1.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0007 security nss-3.19.1-8.el6_7.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0007 security nss-sysinit-3.19.1-8.el6_7.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0007 security nss-tools-3.19.1-8.el6_7.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0370 security nss-util-3.19.1-5.el6_7.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0063 security ntp-4.2.6p5-5.el6_7.4.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0063 security ntpdate-4.2.6p5-5.el6_7.4.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0008 security openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.2.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0301 security openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.4.x86_64
RHSA-2016:0005 security rpcbind-0.2.0-11.el6_7.x86_64
updateinfo list done
```

I have two questions:

when I run the following yum command:

```
yum update -y
```

dose this yum command will be installed all the missing security patch?? ( as I mentioned in the list )

when `yum update -y` completed to installed all patches,

is it mean that my linux redhat machine version 6.x is fully updated with all patches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes to both.  See [RHEL documentation on yum](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-yum.html#sec-Updating_Packages)

I say in general because it really relies on a number of things in the backend, like the repository you're connected to.  This is usually a Red Hat-approved system so you can have some level of confidence that you'll get all of the correct updates.  If you have packages that you installed by hand via RPM, that may not be updated if the package didn't come from a repository you're connected to.